# Test Oracle connection in .Net installer during install without first installing Oracle client

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, 64-bit

We have a 64 bit .net web application that needs to be able to connect to Oracle. One of the requirements is that during the install we collect the database connection information and test that we can connect. It appears that the installer is running as a 32 bit process and I'm including the 64 bit Oracle client files, which should be fine once everything is installed, but even if I install the instant client manually first, the installer fails (likely due to the client being 64 bit).

Anyone have any good suggestions? Changing the requirements to run a configuration utility *after* installing isn't out of the question, at least not in my mind; I haven't actually run that by the business people yet.

UPDATE: I am looking at Wix now. We are currently using a .vdproj and it is my understanding that Wix is how setup project will be created in VS 2012.

UPDATE 2: A bit more background: we are converting from System.Data.OracleClient (deprecate) to the official Oracle distributions. Previously we had a reference to the OracleClient assembly and everything worked. Now I'm trying to reference the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess assembly from the Custom Action, but during install I get a "couldn't find assembly" error.